# Model comparison in SPSS

Tags: mixed-model, spss

I have two models with 24 variables in each. I want to see how adding an extra variable (the variable in study) affects the outcome. I used generalised linear mixed models for both models.(GENLINMIXED comman). How do I save the output of the models and compare them? I would like to do what ANOVA in R does. Compare the two models and find the P value to check if there is significant difference between the two models. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The output from the model containing the extra variable should provide a direct Wald test of that variable on top of the others in the model. The estimation method currently used in GENLINMIXED uses residual pseudo-likelihoods, so models with different sets of fixed effects can't be directly compared as one would do with a maximum likelihood estimation approach in a linear mixed model.